# Sending an activation email with membership methods in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send an activation email to my users in ASP.NET.I should point out that I make users with create user wizard indirectly. I mean I use membership methods and create the user manually. What should I do? please show me by some codes.

```
Membership.CreateUser(TextBox1.Text, result.ToString(), TextBox1.Text);
Roles.AddUserToRole(TextBox1.Text, "Reviewer");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ASP.Net membership doesn't have out-of-the-box sending activation email feature after user is created.

Since you create a user by yourself, you can easily call a SendEmail method right after that.

[Sending email from ASP.Net 4 – C# sample code](http://bradkingsley.com/sending-email-from-asp-net-4-c-sample-code/)

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;

var membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(..., out status);

if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
  SendEmail(...);


public void SendEmail(MailAddress from, MailAddress to, 
  string subject, string body)
{
  var message = new MailMessage();

  message.From = from;
  message.To.Add(to);

  message.Subject = subject;
  message.Body = body;
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;

  var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost");
  smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your great answer. but how can distinguish that a emil is a success one?

Comment: As long as smpt server is configured properly, you are fine. However, you can only checked in mail server if the email is bounced, since email is relaying.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own MembershipProvider. If you are using SQL Server as your membership data store, you can inherit from SqlMembershipProvider, override its CreateUser method, and place your email code in the custom method. You will need to tell your app to use your custom Membership provider by placing something like this in your web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MyMembershipProviderNamespace.MyMembershipProvider, MyMembershipProviderAssembly" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```